# Django forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple emite: Select a valid choice. [''] is not one of the available choices

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Estou tentando usar um *checkbox* pra selecionar itens numa lista, porém me retorna o seguinte erro:

```
Select a valid choice. [''] is not one of the available choices.
```

**models.py** do app:

```
from django.db import models
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm

class Student(models.Model):

    TAKE_COMPUTER_CHOICES = (
        ('sim', 'Sim'),
        ('nao', 'Não'),
    )
    COMPUTER_TYPE_CHOICES = (
        ('windows', 'Windows'),
        ('linux', 'Linux'),
        ('mac', 'Mac'),
    )
    QUESTI0N_CHOICES = (
        ('resposta_1', 'Obter um diferencial no mercado de trabalho'),
        ('resposta_2', 'Aumentar meu salário'),
        ('resposta_3', 'Criar um site ou aplicativo'),
        ('resposta_4', 'Fazer trabalho social'),
        ('resposta_5', 'Apoiar o crescimento do meu futuro negócio'),
        ('resposta_6', 'Desenvolver habilidade digital'),
        ('resposta_7', 'Aumentar minha criatividade'),
        ('resposta_8', 'Aprender a lidar com problemas complexos'),
        ('resposta_9', 'Melhorar minha habilidade de colaboração'),
        ('resposta_10', 'Ter uma carreira alternativa'),
        ('resposta_11', 'Compreender melhor o mundo digital'),
        ('resposta_12', 'Ampliar as possibilidades de minha carreira.'),
        ('resposta_13', 'Ter mais agilidade e dinamismo.'),
        ('resposta_14', 'Desenvolver habilidade lógica'),
        ('resposta_15', 'Melhorar meu desempenho acadêmico.'),
        ('resposta_16', 'Ganhar eficiência - Fazer mais com menos.'),
        ('resposta_17', 'Melhorar minha auto-estima.'),
        ('resposta_18', 'Trabalhar colaborativamente com outros profissionais'),
        ('resposta_19', 'Desenvolver habilidade analítica.'),
        ('resposta_20', 'Empoderamento e Autonomia'),
    )

    cpf = models.CharField(
        max_length=14, unique = True, verbose_name = 'CPF')
    ra = models.CharField(
        max_length=10, unique= True, verbose_name='RA')
    takeComputer = models.CharField(
        max_length=3, choices=TAKE_COMPUTER_CHOICES, verbose_name='Você levará seu computador pessoal?')
    computerType = models.CharField(
        max_length=7, choices=COMPUTER_TYPE_CHOICES, verbose_name='Qual o sistema operacional do seu notebook?:', blank=True)
    question = models.CharField(
        max_length=100, choices=QUESTI0N_CHOICES, verbose_name='Como a habilidade de saber programar pode ajudar minha carreira?'
    )

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    termAccepted = models.BooleanField(default=1, verbose_name='Eu li e aceito o uso da minha imagem')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ra

class StudentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ['cpf',
                'ra',
                'takeComputer',
                'computerType',
                'question',
                'termAccepted',]

    TAKE_COMPUTER_CHOICES = (
        ('sim', 'Sim'),
        ('nao', 'Não'),
    )
    QUESTI0N_CHOICES = (
        ('resposta_1', 'Obter um diferencial no mercado de trabalho'),
        ('resposta_2', 'Aumentar meu salário'),
        ('resposta_3', 'Criar um site ou aplicativo'),
        ('resposta_4', 'Fazer trabalho social'),
        ('resposta_5', 'Apoiar o crescimento do meu futuro negócio'),
        ('resposta_6', 'Desenvolver habilidade digital'),
        ('resposta_7', 'Aumentar minha criatividade'),
        ('resposta_8', 'Aprender a lidar com problemas complexos'),
        ('resposta_9', 'Melhorar minha habilidade de colaboração'),
        ('resposta_10', 'Ter uma carreira alternativa'),
        ('resposta_11', 'Compreender melhor o mundo digital'),
        ('resposta_12', 'Ampliar as possibilidades de minha carreira.'),
        ('resposta_13', 'Ter mais agilidade e dinamismo.'),
        ('resposta_14', 'Desenvolver habilidade lógica'),
        ('resposta_15', 'Melhorar meu desempenho acadêmico.'),
        ('resposta_16', 'Ganhar eficiência - Fazer mais com menos.'),
        ('resposta_17', 'Melhorar minha auto-estima.'),
        ('resposta_18', 'Trabalhar colaborativamente com outros profissionais'),
        ('resposta_19', 'Desenvolver habilidade analítica.'),
        ('resposta_20', 'Empoderamento e Autonomia'),
    )

    question = forms.ChoiceField(label='Como a habilidade de saber programar pode ajudar minha carreira?', choices=QUESTI0N_CHOICES, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
    takeComputer = forms.ChoiceField(label='Você levará seu computador pessoal?', choices=TAKE_COMPUTER_CHOICES, widget=forms.RadioSelect)
```

**views.py** do app:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import *

def create_student(request):
    form = StudentForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid() and form.cleaned_data['termAccepted'] == True:
        student = form.save()

        request.session['student_id'] = student.id
        return redirect('registrations:create_student')

    return render(request, 'student-form-registration.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que você pode fazer é alterar o campo **question** da classe **Student** para [ArrayField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/pt-br/2.1/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield). E na classe **StudentForm** alterar o campo **question** para **forms.MultipleChoiceField**. Assim você consegue salvar todas as opções inseridas pelo usuário.

Comment: Olá @J. Pedro A. realmente dessa forma resolvi meu problema porém estava vendo que usando ArrayField eu ficaria condicionado a usar só Postgres, Será mesmo?

Comment: Sim, infelizmente precisa do postgres. É um campo exclusivo, não sei se outros bancos possuem esse tipo de integração, em que adicionam campos como o ArrayField.